# Running Junit tests from a FileTree in Gradle

Tags: xml, gradle, groovy, junit, ant

I have a Gradle file(test.gradle) that is currently reading from an XML file that contains the class names to determine which tests to run. The classes to test are filtered(into a filetree) from the XML and then run using groovy's ant.junit(). This is done mainly because there are separate Bamboo agents in which particular tests need to run which is determined based on the property provided. I want to run the tasks in each of the agents in parallel. ant.junit does not have something like the maxParallelForks option to specify the exact number of JVMs to bring up in parallel.

Things happening currently:
- In bamboo the test.gradle is renamed to build.gradle. It unzips a jar with all the classes and puts them in the target build directory. 
- There is a task that filters the classes to test(based on an XML provided) from the target build directory based on a property provided in the Bamboo config into a filetree. 
- Then the ant.junit runs the tests using the following:

```
batchtest(todir: "${testDir}") {
      ant.filelist(dir: "${targetDir}/build", files: 
      filteredTests.join(","))
}
```

- Ant does not seem to have an option to choose number of parallel JVM forks to run at a time. I am trying to move these tests to java hoping to be able to set a jvm argument that could set something like the maxParallelFork option. Or just run the filetree in a gradle test task that is dependent on the task that does the filtering. What is my best option?

Things tried:
- I have tried to change the task(the one that filters tests into a filetree and runs them using ant) type to a test. But that does not seem to work. My assumption is since there is no project structure and things are picked from the unzipped jar, the test task does not know how to run them.
- I tried to create a separate gradle test task(that would be dependent on the filtering task) which would include the fileTree. But the run does not seem to find the classes from the included tests. Do I need to mention the directory from where they need to be picked?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your xml was something like

```
<tests>
   <test>foo.bar.Test1</test>
   <test>foo.bar.Test2</test>
</tests>
```

You could do something like

```
task unzipTestClasses(type:Copy) {
   from zipTree('path/to/testClasses.zip')
   into "$buildDir/testClasses" 
}   
task runTestClasses(type:Test) {
   dependsOn 'unzipTestClasses' 
   testClassesDirs = "$buildDir/testClasses"  
   def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(file('path/to.xml'))
   include root.tests.test.collect { "${it.text().replace('.', '/')}.class" } 
}
```